# How to block to open default Facebook sharing in UIActivityViewController in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

in my application want to open custom pop up in UIActivityViewController. So i don't want to open default sharing pop up in facebook. So how to dismiss that pop up or how to block to open that pop up in iOS.
Please give me solution ...

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dismissPopup) name:dismissMJPopUp object: nil];

        //ReferFriendVC *okpopup=[[ReferFriendVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"ReferFriendVC" bundle:nil];
       //  [self presentPopupViewController:okpopup animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationSlideBottomTop];

         UIPopoverController *popup;
         MyActivityItemProvider *message = [[MyActivityItemProvider alloc] init];
         NSArray *activityItems;
         UIImage *myImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"];
         activityItems = @[message, myImage];


         NSArray * applicationActivities = nil;

         UIActivityViewController * activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities];

         activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[
                                                          UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                                          UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                                          UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                                          UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                                          UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                                          UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                                          UIActivityTypePrint,
                                                          UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo                                                          // Whatever you want to exclude
                                                          ];

         if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")){

             activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView =
            self.view;
         }
         if(isiPhone)
         {
            [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

         }
         else{
            popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityViewController];
             [popup presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, screenheight, 768, 0)inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
         }
         [activityViewController setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(NSString *act, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError)
          {

              NSLog(@"act type %@",act);
              NSString *ServiceMsg = nil;
              if ( [act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail] )
                  ServiceMsg = @"Mail sent";
              NSLog(@"mail sent");
              if ( [act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeAssignToContact] )
                  ServiceMsg = @"Post on twitter, ok!";

              if ( [act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook] )
                  ServiceMsg = @"Post on facebook, ok!";
              [popup dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

          }];
```

And in myActivityItemProvide.h

```
#import "MyActivityItemProvider.h"


@implementation MyActivityItemProvider


- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
{
    if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]) {
        NSLog(@"mail method called ");
//
        if([AppDelegate NetworkRechability])
        {
            //        FrindListVC *leavefeed=[[FrindListVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"FrindListVC" bundle:nil];
            //        [self.navigationController pushViewController:leavefeed animated:YES];

            FBSDKAppInviteContent *content1 =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
            content1.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fb.me/4931252562362626805"];
            //optionally set previewImageURL
            content1.appInvitePreviewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://files.parsdrterfsdfetfss.com/79580e8563-55656cc-456455f2-a20f-7f69e783b14d/tfss-f9e2626e-dfsdfsfsdfsdf519c-4ca3-ae47-015ffeaad0f7-fbinvite-01.png"];

            // present the dialog. Assumes self implements protocol `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate`
            [FBSDKAppInviteDialog showWithContent:content1
                                         delegate:self];

          //   [[[self parentViewController] parentViewController] presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
//            activityViewController.view.hidden=YES;


        }
        else
        {

            UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Internet Not Available" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [errorAlert show];
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

        }

    }


    return @"No provider";
}
- (void)appInviteDialog:(FBSDKAppInviteDialog *)appInviteDialog didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"error %@",error);
}
- (void)appInviteDialog:(FBSDKAppInviteDialog *)appInviteDialog didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)result
{
    // NSLog(@"result %@",result);
}
- (id) activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController { return @""; }
@end
```

Comment: show your tried code

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude or block to open default Facebook sharing in `UIActivityViewController` using below code:

```
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]
```